# Using gatling Login goes wrong

Tags: scala, rest, oauth, gatling

Please help me out! I use Gatling 3.4.1 and here I have the first part login script, it goes wrong in the post call. I have a good working JMeter script that does the login succesful. It looks allright to my knowledge, but maybe I'm missing something.

here is my gatling code and trace log. Maybe someone can see the problem.

```
 val httpProtocol: HttpProtocolBuilder = http
    .baseUrl(s"$oAuth2IdpAuthenticationBaseURL")
    .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
    .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("nl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3")
    .header("Accept", "*/*")
    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
    .header("Cache-Control","no-cache")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0")
    .proxy(Proxy(proxyHostURL,proxyHostPort))

  val step1Get_interaction_code: ChainBuilder = exec(
    http("get_interaction_code_step_1")
      .get(s"$oAuth2IdpAuthenticationBaseURL/auth")
      .queryParam("response_type", oAuth2ResponseType)
      .queryParam("state", "nothing")
      .queryParam("client_id", oAuth2ClientID)
      .queryParam("scope", oAuth2Scope_IDP)
      .queryParam("redirect_uri", oAuth2RedirectUri)

      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(currentLocationRegex("""interaction\/(\S*)[?]""").saveAs("interaction_code"))
    )
    .exec(getCookieValue(CookieKey("_csrf").saveAs("csrf_token")))
    .exec(
      http("post_login_step_2")
        .post(s"$oAuth2IdpAuthenticationBaseURL/interaction/"+"${interaction_code}"+"/login")
        .header("Content-Type", s"$oauth2TokenRequestContentType")
        .formParam("_csrf", "${csrf_token}")
        .formParam("username", s"$username")
        .formParam("password", s"$password")
        .check(status.is(200))
    )

  val scn: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Get financialitems from customer")
    .exec( // get the IDP access code
      step1Get_interaction_code
    )

  setUp(
    scn.inject(
      //      rampUsers(5) during (10)
      atOnceUsers(1)
    )
  ).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

The trace log, extracted and de-personalized:

```
=========================
...
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/UI922226/AppData/Local/Coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Workspace/git/apigw-load-testing/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
11:05:18.733 [TRACE] i.g.a.Gatling$ - Starting
...
...
GET /auth?response_type=code&state=nothing&client_id=25708ced-5be7-41fd-ba67-5f5c48594b67&scope=openid+Customers.Internal.Write+Customers.Internal.Read&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200 HTTP/1.1
...
...
11:05:22.351 [DEBUG] i.n.h.s.SslHandler ...
11:05:22.487 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.HttpAppHandler - Read msg='DefaultHttpResponse(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
...
...
11:05:22.489 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.HttpAppHandler - ...
11:05:22.513 [TRACE] i.g.h.e.r.DefaultStatsProcessor - 
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Request:
get_interaction_code_step_1: OK 
=========================
Session:
Session(Get financialitems from customer,1,Map(gatling.http.ssl.sslContexts -> io.gatling.http.util.SslContexts@797b5fb8, ...
=========================
HTTP request:
GET https://account.host.com/auth?response_type=code&state=nothing&client_id=25708ced-5be7-41fd-ba67-5f5c48594b67&scope=openid+Customers.Internal.Write+Customers.Internal.Read&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200
...
...
=========================
HTTP response:
status=
302 Found
...
...
body=
Redirecting to <a href="/interaction/v-nK_uVPtHetCFrELFS0D?">/interaction/v-nK_uVPtHetCFrELFS0D?</a>.
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
11:05:22.513 [DEBUG] i.g.h.e.t.HttpTxExecutor - Sending request=get_interaction_code_step_1 uri=...
11:05:22.514 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.HttpAppHandler - Write request WritableRequest{request=DefaultFullHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1, content: ...
GET /interaction/v-nK_uVPtHetCFrELFS0D? HTTP/1.1
...
...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
...
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Request:
get_interaction_code_step_1 Redirect 1: OK 
=========================
Session:
Session(Get financialitems from customer,1,Map(gatling.http.cache.baseUrl -> https://account.host.com, gatling.http.cache.dns -> ...
HTTP request:
GET https://account.host,com/interaction/v-nK_uVPtHetCFrELFS0D?
...
...
=========================
HTTP response:
status=
200 OK
...
...
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
...
POST /interaction/v-nK_uVPtHetCFrELFS0D/login HTTP/1.1
...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Request:
post_login_step_2: OK 
=========================
Session:
Session(Get financialitems from customer,1,Map(gatling.http.cache.baseUrl -> https://account.host.com, gatling.http.cache.dns -> ...
=========================
HTTP request:
POST https://account.tst.essent.nl/interaction/v-nK_uVPtHetCFrELFS0D/login
...
cookies=
_interaction.sig=7fuyn7xZYS1enRxr7uVgkGN9RhQ, domain=account.tst.essent.nl, path=/interaction/v-nK_uVPtHetCFrELFS0D, maxAge=3600s, secure, HTTPOnly, SameSite=Lax
_interaction=v-nK_uVPtHetCFrELFS0D, domain=account.tst.essent.nl, path=/interaction/v-nK_uVPtHetCFrELFS0D, maxAge=3600s, secure, HTTPOnly, SameSite=Lax
_csrf=qyTaOFCDM7jg3jUpr20Eisqc, path=/
stringBody=FormUrlEncodedRequestBody{contentType='application/x-www-form-urlencoded', charset=UTF-8, content=_csrf=qyTaOFCDM7jg3jUpr20Eisqc&username=SOMEUSERNAME%40HOST.com&password=SOMEPASSWORD}
proxy=HttpProxyServer{realm=null, securedPort=8080, securedAddress=proxy.rwe.com/153.100.71.51:8080, host='proxy.rwe.com', port=8080}
=========================
HTTP response:
status=
200 OK
...
body=
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
                <div class="login--card card">
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <h3 class="login--title">
                            Oeps. Er ging iets mis!     **<----- here it goes wrong!**
                        </h3>

                        
                        <p>
                            Probeer het opnieuw         **<----- Try again!**
                        </p>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>

...             
</html>

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
...
```

Comment: Your question is way too application specific to get a generic answer. You should compare your request payloads between your Gatling simulation and something else that works to figure out what's missing/what's wrong. Note: you should upgrade from Gatling 3.4.1 to 3.6.1.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLANDELLE, in my organization I have no sparring partners for these problems, I agree it is too apps specific, but will stuggle on. I have plans to upgrade

Comment: Try comparing request payloads with your web browser (network in dev tools) or your existing JMeter scripts and spotting the difference .

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, and that did the trick, after long hours figured it out and succeeded to complete the login flow, thanks for the help @StéphaneLANDELLE

Comment: Great! Have fun with Gatling!